# Within an existing 1D HeightMap, how can I find valid positions to create buildings that are spaced apart?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to loop over a heightmap that has been previously generated to find valid spaces that buildings can be placed. Each valid segment is three tiles long in length, at minimal. I'm trying to aim for the middle of such segments so that every one has a single valid location.

At the moment, my code for this is able to locate the segments, but not filter out the tiles on the sides. I've been trying to figure out how to write this, but have been stuck doing so. Here's the code I have thus far:

```
void findValidBuildingPositions()
{
    int whmpl = worldHeightmap.Count - 1;

    List<Vector3> buildingPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    List<int> heightmap = worldHeightmap;

    for (int i = 0; i < whmpl; i++)
    {
        int _in = i + 1;
        int _il = i - 1;

        int iPos = worldHeightmap[i];

        if (_in < whmpl && _il > 0)
        {
            int iNext = worldHeightmap[_in];
            int iLast = worldHeightmap[_il];

            if (iNext == iPos && iPos == iLast)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(i, iPos, 1);

                if (!buildingPositions.Contains(position))
                {
                    buildingPositions.Add(position);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

What is the best way to filter out the two sides so that only the middle remains in place, when dealing with the context of the loop as a whole?

Comment: so i dont understant if you build automatically the buidings at the middle of each segment, so each segment has only one building, or if your buildings are already built and you want keep only those at middle and eliminate the other? so in this case where is your list of buildings built

Comment: To understand your problem your segments are defined like these for example: (1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,5,5,5) -> first segment: length=5 height=1, second: l=4 h=3, third: l=3 h=5? when the segment which has length of 4 you choose the position 3 (if begins at 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have rewritten your method to return only the valid positions:

```
private List<Vector3> findValidBuildingPositions(List<int> worldHeightmap)
{
    int number = worldHeightmap.Count;
    if (number == 0) return null;

    List<Vector3> buildingPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int iHeight = worldHeightmap[i];
        int count = 0;
        //find the length of the segment (number of tiles at same height)
        while (worldHeightmap[i] == iHeight)
        {
            count++;
            i++;
            if (i == number) break;
        }

        var middlePosOfSegment = count % 2 == 0 ? i - count / 2 : i - 1 - count / 2;
        buildingPositions.Add(new Vector3(middlePosOfSegment, iHeight, 1));


        if (i == number) break;
    }

    return buildingPositions;
}
```

The return values are Vector3 (num tile (begins to 0), height, 1)

so when the number of tiles is even i choose the middle value just after +1 tile

Comment: Would be useful to explain the algorithm in your answer too (e.g. search heightmap for sections of equal height, bumping counter, divide by 2 etc)

Comment: 1) i search and count consecutives number(height here) equal so i have the length of a segment .  2) and after i search the position number of middle of segment following length of segment is odd or even.

Comment: i have refactored my code, i think its easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you! MUCH more efficient then the process I was using prior - I was placing the markers, and then using raycasts to eliminate which was which.

Comment: I did add an if (count >= 3) - otherwise it tends to find every free space. Other then that, it works perfectly.

Comment: yes i didnt test that becasue you say minimal 3 tiles per segment!!